# Qual è il significato di "bolgia" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia della bambina perduta*, di Elena Ferrante, ho letto:

> Mi ricordai di quando mi rivolgevo a lui per sapere di Pasquale o di Enzo. C’era sempre bisogno di un santo in Paradiso per orientarsi nella calcolata opacità del mondo di sotto e Nino, sebbene estraneo a qualsiasi santità, mi era stato d’aiuto. Ora che i santi stavano precipitando all’inferno, per sapere di lui non avevo a chi rivolgermi. Notizie inaffidabili mi arrivarono solo dalla mala **bolgia** dei suoi molti avvocati.

Non capisco cosa significa "bolgia" in questa frase. Ho cercato il vocabolo in alcuni dizionari e, nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bolgia/) per esempio ho trovato

> Fig., luogo dove si stia male e vi sia gran confusione

ma non sembra che questo possa essere il senso nel brano precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La derivazione è quella indicata nella risposta precedente, ed è corretto utilizzarlo al singolare (vedi il link alla Treccani). Per bolgia (sottinteso: infernale) si intende appunto un luogo, anche figurato o una situazione particolarmente caotica e ostile.
Credo che nel brano indicato indichi l'insieme degli avvocati, definito bolgia in senso spregiativo, in quanto la loro consultazione ha solo generato confusione.

Answer (score 4):

È una sorta di singolare di https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malebolge (uno dei cerchi dell'Inferno di Dante, particolarmente appropriato agli avvocati...), immagino. Non so se sia standard usarlo così al singolare però.

Answer (score 1):

Bolgia è un termine piuttosto comune, viene usato come sinonimo di "folla", "gran numero di persone", in genere con connotati negativi dal punto di vista del rumore/confusione/densità di persone.

Validi esempi sono "Bolgia allo stadio, "bolgia al centro commerciale", "bolgia in discoteca"..."Bolgia in chiesa" invece è un po' più improbabile (ma non impossibile, se la chiesa è davvero piena: mi è capitato di sentirlo qualche volta per matrimoni, o per cerimonie di paese)

Una bolgia di avvocati è in un certo senso un "rafforzativo" di avvocati: la gente comune fa uso di un solo avvocato, così è diventato un topos in letteratura e nei film l'evidenziare il livello di un antagonista mostrando la "potenza di fuoco" di cui dispone attraverso l'uso di team di avvocati e loro assistenti. (in realtà è una formula piuttosto utilizzata anche nel business, da parte delle grosse aziende per spaventare le piccole aziende, ma restiamo nel letterario che è meglio)

Comment: In questo caso c'è il riferimento all'inferno e la locuzione “mala bolgia” si rifà ovviamente alla *Commedia*.